# Transaction flow in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When a client application proposes a transaction , does it send the proposed transaction only to the endorsing peers of the organisation which it is a member of or does it send it to all the endorsing peers in the channel?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer to this is that the proposed transaction (or the transaction proposal to be precise) will only be sent to the set of endorsing peers specified by the endorsement policy.  Not all the endorsing peers in the channel will receive the  transaction proposal.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you construct your transaction proposal. Ultimately you are in charge of where the proposal is sent.

In the node sdk (v1.2), for example, you can specify `targets` in your [ChaincodeInvokeRequest](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/global.html#ChaincodeInvokeRequest). If you have service discovery enabled when you join the channel and do not specify the `targets` it will send the proposal to all peers discovered.

The endorsement policy *does not* dictate which peers the transaction proposal is sent to. It dictates which peers must mark the proposal as valid in order for the transaction to be committed to the ledger.

The fabric docs have a section on [transaction flow](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/txflow.html) that go into more detail on what the entire process looks like.